# ARKit – How to convert a PNG file into a OBJ file?

Tags: swift, png, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am currently studying ARKit and I wish to display a 2d image in 3D environment. The image I want to display is a `.png` file.

Is there a way to convert this into an `.obj` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no way to convert a 2D `.png` raster file into 3D `.obj` geometry file**. These formats are different like `green apple` and `small button`...

Although, the simplest way to see your image in ARKit's or SceneKit's 3D environment is to assign it on a 3D plane as a texture. Here's how you can do it:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
sceneView.session.run(config)

let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "dir/image.png")
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```